# R: mutate() and ifelse() do now preserve original value of the colums

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to assign column `MAYBE` values to column `NO_HIT`, if the `MAYBE` column has value `1`. In other cases, I would like to preserve the original value of `NO_HIT` column.

My original table:

```
GCA_id          family               `NO HIT` MAYBE   HIT
<chr>           <chr>                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
GCA_000091205.1 Cyanidiaceae                1    NA    NA
GCA_000341285.1 Cyanidiaceae               NA     1    NA
GCA_000350225.2 Gigartinaceae              NA     1    NA
GCA_000372725.1 Noelaerhabdaceae            1    NA    NA
GCA_002049455.2 Bangiaceae                  1    NA    NA
GCA_002049455.2 Bangiaceae                 NA     1     1
GCA_002205965.3 Solieriaceae               NA     1     1
```

But when I try `` table %>%  mutate(`NO HIT` = ifelse(MAYBE == 1, 1, `NO HIT`)) ``, it ignores the original values of column `NO_HIT` and assigns solely values of `MAYBE` column, resulting in:

```
GCA_id          family               `NO HIT` MAYBE   HIT
<chr>           <chr>                   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
GCA_000091205.1 Cyanidiaceae               NA    NA    NA
GCA_000341285.1 Cyanidiaceae                1     1    NA
GCA_000350225.2 Gigartinaceae               1     1    NA
GCA_000372725.1 Noelaerhabdaceae           NA    NA    NA
GCA_002049455.2 Bangiaceae                 NA    NA    NA
GCA_002049455.2 Bangiaceae                  1     1     1
GCA_002205965.3 Solieriaceae                1     1     1
```

Comment: from `?ifelse`:    Missing values in ‘test’ give missing values in the result.

Comment: Try `ifelse(!is.na(MAYBE) & MAYBE == 1, MAYBE, `NO HIT`)`

Comment: someone please post one of these comments as an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer in the comments, is this what you're looking for?

```
tib <- tibble::tribble(
                ~id,            ~family, ~no_hit, ~maybe, ~hit,
  "GCA_000091205.1",     "Cyanidiaceae",       1,     NA,   NA,
  "GCA_000341285.1",     "Cyanidiaceae",      NA,      1,   NA,
  "GCA_000350225.2",    "Gigartinaceae",      NA,      1,   NA,
  "GCA_000372725.1", "Noelaerhabdaceae",       1,     NA,   NA,
  "GCA_002049455.2",       "Bangiaceae",       1,     NA,   NA,
  "GCA_002049455.2",       "Bangiaceae",      NA,      1,    1,
  "GCA_002205965.3",     "Solieriaceae",      NA,      1,    1
  )


tib %>%
  mutate(no_hit = if_else(!is.na(maybe) & maybe == 1, maybe, no_hit))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   id              family           no_hit maybe   hit
#>   <chr>           <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 GCA_000091205.1 Cyanidiaceae          1    NA    NA
#> 2 GCA_000341285.1 Cyanidiaceae          1     1    NA
#> 3 GCA_000350225.2 Gigartinaceae         1     1    NA
#> 4 GCA_000372725.1 Noelaerhabdaceae      1    NA    NA
#> 5 GCA_002049455.2 Bangiaceae            1    NA    NA
#> 6 GCA_002049455.2 Bangiaceae            1     1     1
#> 7 GCA_002205965.3 Solieriaceae          1     1     1

# Created on 2023-01-09 with reprex v2.0.2
```